# How to make .onclick function perform the animation again from the start and listen if its already completed

Tags: jquery, function, animation, onclick, repeat

When I press button 2, I want the action of Button 1 to disappear and vice versa.

**https://jsfiddle.net/9f8pceeu/12/**

```
$(".btn1").on('click', function(){
```

Comment: please post fiddle of your problem!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9b8eozgx/

Comment: What is the issue? Even changing `one` to `on` it works good! can u elaborate more!

Comment: when I click on another button after clicking on the first one. the first one doesnt work anymore

Comment: The buttons only work once even after changing 'one' to 'on'

Comment: not getting actually what your attempting. Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/9b8eozgx/1/)

Comment: i have updated the jquery code for the second last button so its easier to explain. The second last button suppose to remove the function performed by the last button

Comment: I want the buttons to refresh their functions when clicked again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show the specific element on click of button then you can set target element in some attribute on button and on click of button you can hide all first and then can `fadeIn` the target element.

Check the below code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").on('click', function() {
    $("p").hide();
    $($(this).data("target")).fadeIn(500);
  });
});
```

```css
.p1 {
  display: none;
}

.p2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button class="btn1" data-target=".p1">Button1</button>
<button class="btn2" data-target=".p2">Button2</button>
<p class="p1">
  Hello :)
</p>
<p class="p2">
  How are you?
</p>
```